# Select row based on date and change value in other column python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In my dataframe (~200k rows), i convert value in column "Date" to week number, based on ISO-standard week:

```
import pandas as pd

df["Week Number"] = df["Date"].dt.week
```

And my df look like this:

```
Date   | Column1 | Week Number
------+---------+--------
1/1/16  | A       | 1
2/1/16  | B       | 1
3/1/16  | C       | 1
8/1/16  | A       | 2
9/1/16  | B       | 2
10/1/16 | C       | 2
15/1/17 | A       | 2
16/1/17 | B       | 2
17/1/17 | C       | 2
```

But i want add +52 in row "Week Number", if this row is from 2017 in column "Date":

```
Date   | Column1 | Week Number
------+---------+--------
1/1/16  | A       | 1
2/1/16  | B       | 1
3/1/16  | C       | 1
8/1/16  | A       | 2
9/1/16  | B       | 2
10/1/16 | C       | 2
15/1/17 | A       | 54
16/1/17 | B       | 54
17/1/17 | C       | 54
```

How make solution in pandas/numpy or something lib in python3?

Comment: You could use `df.iloc[df.Date.str.split('/').str[-1] >= '17', 'Week Number'] += 52` but I don't advocate string operations on dates, use Zero's instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
In [4210]: df.loc[df['Date'].dt.year >= 2017, 'Week Number'] += 52

In [4211]: df
Out[4211]:
        Date Column1  Week Number
0 2016-01-01       A            1
1 2016-02-01       B            1
2 2016-03-01       C            1
3 2016-08-01       A            2
4 2016-09-01       B            2
5 2016-10-01       C            2
6 2017-01-15       A           54
7 2017-01-16       B           54
8 2017-01-17       C           54
```

Or, use `np.where`

```
In [4222]: np.where(df['Date'].dt.year.ge(2017), 
                    df['Week Number'].add(52),
                    df['Week Number'])
      ...:
Out[4222]: array([ 1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2, 54, 54, 54], dtype=int64)
```

---

Details

```
In [4212]: df
Out[4212]:
        Date Column1  Week Number
0 2016-01-01       A            1
1 2016-02-01       B            1
2 2016-03-01       C            1
3 2016-08-01       A            2
4 2016-09-01       B            2
5 2016-10-01       C            2
6 2017-01-15       A           54
7 2017-01-16       B           54
8 2017-01-17       C           54

In [4213]: df.dtypes
Out[4213]:
Date           datetime64[ns]
Column1                object
Week Number             int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: is it possible to generalize the solution like `df['Date'].dt.week + ((df['Date'] - pd.to_datetime('01-01-2016')).dt.days/365).astype(int)*52`